# Admin is denied to change teams rights

Tags: azure-devops

I was changing Teams rights in DevOps.
Unfortunatly, I messed up and eventualy I modified the default team rights. Please note that I belong to this team.

I set "Edit project-level information" to "deny".
Now I can't set it back because... well... I am denied to edit :(

Still, I am an admin of the project so I should be able to recover from this situation, shouldn't I?

What I tried :

Create a new team and inherit it from "Project administrator". But obviously it doesn't work because I am already in this team.

I also tried to move the default team to another team but it is denied as well.

Does an Azure Devops admin can recover this situation ?

Any help apperciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution found here:

I removed myself from the team I messed up.
Then I was able to update the rights of this group then add myself back to it